# Android - Adding to MediaStore strips Exif data.

Tags: android, android-image

I have some images saved on external storage. When I call:

```
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),
                fullPath, "IMG_"+System.currentTimeMillis(),null);
```

I check in the gallery and the file is there but its stripped the date back to 1970.  Any ideas of why this might be or how to get around it?